# python regular expression letters in a row

Tags: python, regex, expression

I would like to write a regular expression in Python that checks if a string does not contain more than 2 same letters in a row, e.g. wood valid, woood not valid
I tried it with

```
[a-zA-z]{,2}
```

but that does not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this would be using a backreference twice:

```
r"([a-zA-Z])\1\1"
```

This checks for the opposite of what you're asking for, so negate the result. If you're using this as a part of a larger regex, remember to change the backreference index if needed.

Comment: Somehow it does not work because when I use the following: regex3 = re.compile("[a-zA-z]\1\1") if regex3.match(string) == None: f.write(string), I still receive results like woood...

Comment: for a back-reference to work you need to add `r` (raw) at start, and you have missed the capturing group also. So `re.compile("[a-zA-z]\1\1")` should be `re.compile(r"([a-zA-z])\1\1")`

Comment: All `r` does is make Python itself not treat `\ ` as an escape character, it's also possible to write this regexp as `"([a-zA-Z])\\1\\1"`, but using `r` makes for more readable code.